# Power Bi calender

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

please I need to make a calendar table to enjoy the privileges of some functions but my date field is formatted with hour minute and seconds and is not related to the automatic calendar that creates power bi.

Who can help me gratefully.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a calculated column to extract just the date part of your DATETIME field. Something like:

```
DateOnly = 
DATE ( 
    YEAR ( TableName[DateTimeField] ),
    MONTH ( TableName[DateTimeField] ),
    DAY ( TableName[DateTimeField] )
)
```